# cuda intrinsic functions sqrtf and powf performance issues

Tags: performance, math, cuda, device, intrinsics

when i convert from `powf` to `__powf` it gives performance improvement to me. but if i convert `sqrtf` to one of which `__fsqrt_[rn,rz,ru,rd]` it slows down. I think they should run at least as fast as sqrtf. What can be the problem?

Regards

Comment: Are you using single precision (`float`) or double precision (`double`) ?

Comment: sqrtf( powf( int, 2 ) ); like that

Comment: Seriously ? Why would you do that ? You're passing integer values to a double precision function and then getting back the original value as a double ?

Comment: =) it was just for example. Of course, i don't do it. It's like sqrtf( powf( int, 2 ) + ... );

Comment: But why would you even call powf to square an integer value - that's horribly inefficient ?

Comment: if you declare what should be done, i really appreciate it. int * int ?

Comment: powf is [automatically converted](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#intrinsic-functions) by `-use-fast-math`.  sqrtf is not.  This says to me these two conversions are in different categories in terms of performance.  This [section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions) of the programming guide may be of interest as well, e.g. you might want to look at `-prec-sqrt=false`

Comment: also, if you post the actual line(s) of code where you are doing this and your requirements, you may get a good answer about how to make it run fast.

Comment: sqrtf() can map to either a fast, approximate single-precision square root, or a slower, IEEE-754 round-to-nearest-or-even square root. __frsqrt_rn() always maps to the IEEE-754 round-to-nearest-or-even square root. sqrtf() maps to the fast approximate square root (1) always for sm_1x targets (2) when -prec-sqrt=false or -use_fast_math is specified for sm_20 and higher targets.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to square an integer (or float for that matter) then you can just multiply the value with itself, i.e. instead of;

```
y = powf(x, 2);
```

use:

```
y = x * x;
```

This avoids using an expensive transcendental function (along with its associated function call overhead) and just generates a single multiply instruction in most cases.

The square root probably can't be avoided but you can use `fsqrtf` rather than `sqrtf` if you only need single precision - this is typically much faster.